# Delete OLDs PDF from iPhone APP in an update

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf, xcode5, updatemodel

I want to replace all my old PDFs for new ones in my iPhone app (that I put in my proyect), but I can not do it. In some cases the app still is showing me old files.... what can be the problem?  I need to delete the old ones from iPhone memory by code to do the update...

any help is really appreciated

```
    NSString *appFolderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSArray *contenido = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: appFolderPath error:nil];

    NSEnumerator *e = [contenido objectEnumerator];
    NSString *filename;
    while ((filename = [e nextObject])) {

        if ([[filename pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"pdf"]) {
            //NSLog(@"Archivo %@", filename); me da el nomber SCEL VAC.pdf
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString *myFilePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
            //NSLog(@"path archivo %@", myFilePath);// me da dentro de documents

            if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:myFilePath] == NO) {
                NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:nil];
                bool success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:myFilePath error:&error1];
                if (success){
                    NSLog(@"instalado %@", myFilePath);
                }
            }else if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:myFilePath] == YES)
            {
                bool success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:myFilePath error:&error1];
                if (success){
                NSLog(@"borrado %@", myFilePath);
                }

                NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:nil];

                bool success2 = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:myFilePath error:&error1];
                if (success2){
                NSLog(@"copiado %@", myFilePath);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change any files in the a main bundle it is readonly.

Thus in your update, you should remove the old PDFS from you project and then they are no longer available in the main bundle.

Comment: Thanks... I've already remove the old PDF from my Project, but in the phone they still are there... I need to know how to remove them by code....

Comment: If they are in the main bundle you can not remove them, the ones in the document directory you should be able to remove.